# Function equal to half period of sinusoid

Tags: trigonometry

I was wondering if there exists a function that fits perfectly into half the period of a sinewave (where the section of interest begins at one zero and ends at a zero).  So, for example, if the function is $\sin(2{\pi} x)$ I was wondering if there exists a non trigonometric function that is equal to the region from $x = 0$ to $x = 0.5$.

Perhaps an ellipse or something?  If there isn't, is there anything simple that'll fit really well?  (I don't want to use some massive power series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $4x(1-x)$ is a decent approximation of $\sin(\pi x)$ on the interval $[0,1]$.

[image]

If you want a more accurate approximation, there are a couple of options:

(1) Use a rational approximation, instead of a polynomial. These are much more difficult to construct, though.

(2) Use a polynomial approximation of higher degree. But, the higher you go, the closer you'll be getting to the "massive power series" that you're trying to avoid.

If you have access to Matlab, an excellent tool for computing polynomial and rational approximations is [chebfun](http://www2.maths.ox.ac.uk/chebfun/).

Answer (score 1):

Take any $C^1$ function $f:[0,1/2]\to \Bbb R$ such that $f\ge 0$, $f(0)=f(1/2)=0$, $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x}$ exists,  and $\lim_{x\to 1/2} \frac{f(x)}{x-1/2}$ exists. Now divide it by $ \sup_{x\in [0,1/2]} |f(x)/\sin(2\pi x)|$, you obtain the desired function.

For example, you can take $f(x) = \exp\left(-\frac{1}{x(1/2-x)}\right)$ (maybe up to some constant factor).